# Copying an ssh-key to multiple servers/logins using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am setting up SSH keys on my servers and I am trying to write a script to copy them all out.  Basically what I want to do is copy the ssh id from server 1 to server 1-10, then log into server 2 and copy the ssh id from server 2 to server 1-10.

I have an array set up and 2 for loops with the ssh-copy-id command, but I am missing the step to log into each server as it comes up in the list.  I realize I will be entering passwords at this point, but it is much easier this way than logging into each one individually.  Can someone help me out?

Also, my work has blocked GitHub, so please don't link to there.  I can't see it :(

Comment: Write a single loop over the servers in a script.

Then run that on your first host.

Then run a loop over all the servers which uses the just-copied credentials to scp the script to each other machine and then ssh in and run it?

Comment: @EtanReisner - I tried scp before and none of the keys worked, that's why I wanted to use ssh-copy-id this time to get the keys on all the servers with as little manipulation as possible.

Comment: I was suggesting using `ssh-copy-id`. That's what the script does. The second loop was going to use the `ssh-copy-id`d credentials *with* scp to push the script that does the `ssh-copy-id` loop to each machine and then run it (via a second call to `ssh`).

Comment: Ah - I think I red it wrong initially.  Why do would I use both ssh-copy-id and scp?  If I am able to successfully move from Server 1 to Server 2 (still not sure how this is accomplished), then why can't I just do an ssh-copy-id?

Comment: Hm... actually my idea would have you input passwords too many times. You want these servers to all be mutually keyed to one another, right? So you want to use `ssh-copy-id` from the first machine and then `ssh hostX cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> extra_keys` for all the other hosts and then `cat extra-keys | ssh hostX cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys` for each host... or something like that I think.

Comment: It is really easy for me to input the passwords while running a script.  That's why I said it's ok above.  Nevermind, I will find another way to do it I guess.  Thanks for trying

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to input them for each server from each server, you want to enter them as few times as possible. What I wrote in my last comment should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following (entirely untested) code should do what you want I believe.

Hosts other than the host you run this on will have entries for themselves in the authorized_keys files if that matters (that could be avoided but requires more work and can likely just as easily be fixed manually if needed).

```
hosts=(hostA hostB hostC hostD ...)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    # Skip the current host.
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "$host" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Copy the current host's id to each other host.
    # Asks for password.
    ssh-copy-id "$host"
done

# Get the id's from each host.
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    # Skip the current host.
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "$host" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    ssh "$host" 'cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub' >> host-ids
done

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    # Skip the current host.
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "$host" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # This might work but I'm not sure.
    ssh-copy-id -i host-ids "$host"
    # If that didn't work then this should.
    #ssh "$host" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' <host-ids
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions, but I just logged into each server and ran the script.  I didn't have time to play with scripts anymore :/  SSH keys still didn't seem to work, but that's for another time/thread.